# Dynamic create environment and run Cypress parallel

Tags: gitlab, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner

We are using Cypress to run our end-2-end-tests in GitLab. Before we run the test we create a dynamic environment. A dynamic environment is an environment which is created with docker-compoe inside the gitlab runner which executes the cypress tests. After the dynamic environment is up fire the tests against this dynamic environment. Everything happens in one `gitlab-runner` so no external deployment to a test environment takes place.

Now we want to move forward and parallelize the cypress run. Its documented here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization and it is working under the assumption that the environment is already there. It creates several GitLab runners and cypress takes care for distribution the scenarios between the runners.

The question is, how to set up a dynamic environment with GitLab which can be shared between GitLab runners? Is it only possible with a dummy deployment to a Kubernetes environment which is prepared for this user case? Do I need create a dynamic environment in each runner? Or any other hints?

Comment: I _think_ I understand what you mean, but could you explain in more detail precisely  what you mean by _dynamic environment_? Ideally, if you're going to parallelize your test cases, they should not be dependent on one another. _Each_ parallel job will create any necessary environment (e.g. like a service container your tests run against). Alternatively, yes, you can do a deploy to a non-production environment and point all your tests running in parallel to that single deployed environment, which is another common pattern.

Comment: Hi @sytech - you already answered the question. The tests are not depending on each other. I hoped that the envionment could be created inside gitlab and then shared by the runners so I do not need an external environment. But seems not to be doable so easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution now looks like this.

We start the environment from docker-compose in each running gitlab-job. This of course reduces the time-saving of parallel execution of tests since gitlab runners are blocked longer. But since it happens in parallel and we are not short on runners its OK for us. An other advantage was that we could keep our current setup with only minimal modifications. In the end we reduced our "run all end 2 end tests" - execution time by about 30%